# DIV position - 2 divs inside div

Tags: html, css

What am i doing wrong - please help me to fix it
All i'm tring to do is to put inside div 2 divs with percentage width
as you can see one of the divs gets out from the div
[image]

```
   <div style="border: 3px solid black; float: right; height: 27px; width:100px">

    <div style="position: relative;border: 3px solid black; float: right; height: 27px; width:50%">1</div>
     <div style="position: relative;border: 3px solid black; float: left; height: 27px; width:50%">1</div>


    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is your child DIVs border attribute. Each one has a 6px border. Try to remove their border and test it again.
Also you don't need to specify relative for their position value. Try this code and tell me the result here.

```
 <div style="border: 3px solid black; float: right; height: 27px; width:100px">
    <div style="float: right; width:50%">Right div</div>
    <div style="float: left; width:50%">Left div</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

They do not fit because of the borders. 50% + 50% + 12px border is more than 100%. If you use a fixed width of 100 px for the outer div, you can use a fixed width of 44px instead of 50% for the inner divs and it should work fine

Comment: Yes. Also, the `position:relative` doesn't do anything, so you might as well take that out. It may interfere with the `float`s in some browsers.

Answer (score 2):

Following on from @Christopher's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8543658/11569), the [box model](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp) sets each box to 50% wide, *then* adds 6px onto each box for the border.

CSS3 introduces [box-sizing](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201104/controlling_width_with_css3_box-sizing/) that lets you control that

Here's an example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kLxX4/) that shows how you could use the new box sizing to do what you need. According to [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=box-sizing) you'll not have much luck with this in IE6 or IE7, and will have to put a -moz prefix on for Firefox.